# Understanding str in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I have the following assembly code:

```
alpha: .space 64    @reserves 64 bytes
i: int 0
   .text
   .align2
   .globalmain
   .func main
main:
      ldr r3,=i      @r3 is address of i
      mov r2,#0      @r2 is 0
      str r2,[r3]    @r2 is stored in r3
L1:
    ldr r3,=i             @r2 is address of i
    ldr r2,[r3]           @r2 is now address of i 
    cmp r2,#16            
    bge exit              @if r2 > 16, then exit (but it is not)
    ldr r3,=i             @r3 is address of i
    ldr r2,[r3]           @r2 is address of i
    add r1,r2,#0x200      @r1 is r2 + 0x200
    ldr r3,=alpha         @r3 is address of first element in array alpha (I think)
    str r1,[r3,r2,asl#2]
    ...
```

I know its alot, but I only have trouble with one part. I commented the parts I do know, or at least I think I know.

The trouble I'm having is with `str r1,[r3,r2,asl#2]`. I know `asl#2` is a left shift, but that's all I really know. Where does r1 get stored, in r3? What would be the result of the `str` command? Can someone explain it for me?

Comment: Does [this help](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFGBDD.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of str in ARM assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310272/explanation-of-str-in-arm-assembly)

Comment: Yes, because _you asked the exact same question twice_ (but the other one is clearer and has better answers).

Comment: indeed I did. I entirely forgot about this

Comment: @artlessnoise My impression is that we prefer to keep open the question which was asked _best_: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/3156750

Comment: @Notlikethat Best is subjective; I have no idea why the other answers got more votes.  It is not significantly better/different imo.  Probably neither will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str r1,[r3,r2,asl#2]
```

value in r2 is arithematic left shifted by (immediate value) 2 and is added to the contents of r3 , to get the memory address at which r1 will be stored.

Comment: Or in 'C' it would be like `int r3[]; r3[r2]=r1;` -- `asl #2` for 32bit sized arrays and `asl #1` is common for 16bit arrays (or shorts).